# How do I participate in the Ubuntu wallpaper contest?

Tags: desktop-background

I am now making some very fancy wallpapers in Blender, and I found there is a contest where you can submit your wallpaper, and the best ones gets included in next Ubuntu release. I  want to participate in 15.04 wallpaper contest, but I need to know

- When does it start?
- How do I participate?
- What is minimal image resolution?
- How many samples must I use in Cycles to make it useful (non-noisy)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt it has started yet. 14.10's contest started in August. This is what [Iain Farrell](https://launchpad.net/~iain-farrell) [had to say](http://design.canonical.com/2014/08/ubuntu-14-10-wallpapers-we-needs-em/):

> 1. Images shouldn’t be too busy and filled with too many shapes and colours, a similar tone throughout is a good rule of thumb.
> 2. A single point of focus, a single area that draws the eye into the image, can also help you avoid something too cluttered.
> 3. The left and top edges are home to Ubuntu’s Launcher and Panel so be careful to consider how your images look in place so as not to clash with the user interface. Try them out on your own desktop, see how they feel.
> 4. Try your image at different aspect ratios to make sure something important isn’t cropped out on smaller/ larger screens at different resolutions.
> 5. Take a look at the wallpapers guidance on [the Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Artwork/Documentation/Backgrounds) regarding the size of images. Our target resolution is 2560 x 1600.
> 6. Break all the rules except the resolution one! :D

Looking at this [OMG! Ubuntu! article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/08/ubuntu-14-10-wallpaper-contest), submissions are apparently made to a Flickr pool.

Comment: 2560x1600... If I set 1920x1080 in Blender and set it to 200%, how much isi t? How much % should I set?(the current version does not fill my screen, but, anyway, my screen is very large(actually it is TV screen)

Comment: Mine was actually bigger:D My screen is over 4000x2400:D

Comment: I am not using focus, as they are nature scenes, instead of close single objects...

Comment: Is it possible to submit more than 1 image in competition?

Comment: I have made 4 images and 2 of them are cool

Comment: @AdriansNetlis Those are questions you should ask in the Flickr group when the competition starts.

Answer (score 1):

Last year for 14.04 the contest started towards the end of January, and I don't see anything about the 15.04 contest yet.

While you are waiting, you can read the [official guidelines](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/Artwork/Trusty/CommunityWallpapers). The desired format is 2560 x 1600 but it should support a variety of sizes listed there.